# How do I render images saved in my database as a field of a model

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I have a model

```
class NewListing(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to= "static", default="static/default_image.jpg", null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    Starting_Bid= models.IntegerField()
    time= models.CharField(max_length= 30)
```

and the model's form

```
class NewListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= NewListing
        fields= ["title", "image", "description", "Starting_Bid"]
```

In my views.py, i want the index url to display a list of all the **Listings** so i wrote this

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings": list(NewListing.objects.all())
            })
```

This is my **index.html** where i tried to display each listing in its own div

```
{% for listing in listings %}
        <div>
                <h3> 
                <a href='listings/{{listing.title}}'> {{listing.title}}</a>
                </h3>
                <p>{{listing.description}}</p>
                <img src='static/{{listing.image}}'>
                <p>{{listing.time}}</p> 
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

The problem is whenever i try to render this page, I get a broken thumbnail instead of the image. How do i fix this?

Comment: try ```<img src='{{ listing.image.url }}'>```

Answer (score 0):

Load static first assuming you have a static folder where all static files are stored

```
{% load static %}
{% for listing in listings %}
    <div>
            <h3> 
            <a href='listings/{{listing.title}}'> {{listing.title}}</a>
            </h3>
            <p>{{listing.description}}</p>
            <img src="{% static ' listing.image.url' %}" >
            <p>{{listing.time}}</p> 
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I replaced my index.html with this but it didn't work. Thing is, I don't even know my images' url. It isn't in my static file folder. The only file there is my styles.css file